# Why is Edge and IE running on my PC if I haven't started them?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to cut down on the number of processes on my system since the PC is starting to feel sluggish.  Going through the processes, instances of Edge and IE caught my eye.  I don't use either one of the browsers, but it seems like something is firing them up.

How can I find out what's firing them up:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I find out what's firing them up?

Edge isn’t running, it’s suspended, which is explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-suspend).  If anything had previously launched it, Windows attempts when you reboot, to restore applications which support doing so in the same state.  As for IE11, pretty much any application which uses it’s Trident engine for displaying Webb content would explain why that’s running.

Suspended UWP applications use minimal resources.  Running in a minimal boot configuration, and enabling each startup entry one by one, is the best way to determine which applications might be starting IE11.  Office, which is running, is the reason IE11 is running.

> When the user minimizes an app Windows waits a few seconds to see whether the user will switch back to it. If they do not switch back within this time window, and no extended execution, background task, or activity sponsored execution is active, Windows suspends the app. An app is also suspended when the lock screen appears as long as no extended execution session, etc. is active in that app.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-suspend)